# Laravel 5.4 App with menu where not all items are "highlighted" when active

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-blade

I adopted this App and am adding more links to this menu, but can't quite figure out how they had it set up to have the active/focused ones highlighted(actual grey). Here's the blade code:

```
<?php
$actions = array(
  ['show', 'Overview', '/customer', 'fa-user'],
  ['edit', 'Change Account Info', '/customer/edit', 'fa-pencil-square-
o'],
  ['editPassword', 'Change Password', '/customer/edit-password', 'fa-
lock'],
  ['editCreditCard', (is_null($customer->creditCard) ? 'Enter ' : 
'Update '). 'Credit Card', '/customer/edit-credit-card', 'fa-credit-
card'],
  ['payment', 'Make Payment', '/payments/create', 'fa-money'],
  ['emailOpting', 'Email Preferences', '/emailOpting/email-opting', 
'fa-envelope-o'],
  ['incident', 'My Support Tickets', '/incidents/index', 'fa-ticket']
);
?>

<div class="element small">
  <h2>Actions</h2>
  <ul>
    @foreach ($actions as $action)
      @if (ends_with(Route::currentRouteAction(), $action[0]))
        <li><i class="fa {{ $action[3] }}"></i> {{ $action[1] }}</li>
      @else
        <li>{!! html_entity_decode(Html::link($action[2], '<i class="fa 
'.$action[3].'"></i> ' . $action[1])) !!}</li>
      @endunless
    @endforeach
  </ul>
</div>
```

I've added the last three links in the array and they work fine as links, but don't highlight when focused or active. I've playing with the html, but every which way it seems to break. The first four links in the array (Overview, Change Account Info, Change Password and Update Credit Card) all turn grey when visited.

Comment: It's all in the `@if (ends_with(Route::currentRouteAction(), $action[0]))` bit.

Comment: Grey color style is about css not Blade

Comment: That's just bootstrap. @ceejayoz, isn't that line just checking if it ends with the current route and then calling the method in the first indices?

Comment: @MattLarson It's checking if the current action matches the action being shown in the menu. Take a close, careful look - if the action matches (i.e. it's outputting the *current* action), it **skips** the `Html::link` - likely appearing in grey as you describe.

Comment: Ah yes. I didn't have my routes just right in the first indices. Thank you so much!